# How to insert random letter to specific word in a sentence using PHP

Tags: php

here is myproblem, i want to make a php function to insert some random letter to specific word.

example :

random letter : a,i,u,e,o

specific word : monkey,deer,tiger,mouse

sentence : a tiger eating a deer, monkeys and rats see from a distance

I want the sentence to be like this:

a tiager eating a dueer, monkeiys and raats see from a distance

Comment: what odd things people want to do

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please bear in mind that this is a place for obtaining help with specific programming issues, and not for soliciting people to write code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sentence = 'a tiger eating a deer, monkeys and rats see from a distance'; // You'll need to load the string into a variable, obviously.

$randomLetterArray = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'); // It's good to set the random letters inside an array so that they can be randomly picked by randomizing the index number.

$specificWordArray = array('monkey', 'deer', 'tiger', 'mouse'); // Words to be altered in an array to easily iterate through.

foreach ($specificWordArray as $specificWord) // Iterating through each of the words to be altered.
{
    $indexOfWord = rand(0, strlen($specificWord)-1); // Getting a random number between 0 and the length (in chars) of the word.
    $partOfWord = substr($specificWord, 0 , $indexOfWord); // Getting a part of the word based on the random number created above.
    // This is more complex.
    // The part of the word created above is concatenated by a random selection of one of the random letters.
    // This in turn is concatenated by the remaining letters in the word.
    $wordReplacement = $partOfWord.$randomLetterArray[rand(0, count($randomLetterArray)-1)].substr($specificWord, $indexOfWord);
    $sentence = str_ireplace($specificWord, $wordReplacement, $sentence); // This replaces the word in the sentence with the new word.
}
echo $sentence;
```

I hope this gives you some ideas into how to approach the problem, and I hope the comments help to give an idea of the functions available to you in PHP.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, but i'm pretty sure there is a faster and easier way to do it.

```
# the magic function
function magicHappensHere ( $letters, $words, $sentence ) {

    $return = '';

    # divide by words
    $sentence_words = explode( ' ', $sentence );

    foreach ( $sentence_words as $value ) {

        # check words
        if ( array_search( $value, $words ) ) {
            # check 'letter' count
            $l_number = sizeof( $letters );

            # create a random letter value
            $rand_letter = rand( 0, ( $l_number-1 ) );

            # create random position to use
            $rand_pos = rand ( 0, strlen( $value ) );

            # change the actual word
            $value = substr_replace( $value, $letters[ $rand_letter ] ,$rand_pos, 0 );
        }

        $return .= $value . ' ';

    }

    # print out new string ( w/out last space )
    return substr( $return, 0, -1 );
}

# define your 'letters'
$letters = array( 'a', 'i', 'u', 'e', 'o' );

# define your 'words'
$words = array( 'monkey', 'deer', 'tiger', 'mouse' );

# define your 'sentence'
$sentence = 'a tiger eating a deer, monkeys and rats see from a distance';

# change text
$new_sentence = magicHappensHere ( $letters, $words, $sentence );

print $new_sentence;

?>
```

Comment: your code only change first word only.but thank you for your help :)